# Before Insert trigger in Derby DB

Tags: mysql, sql, database, javafx, derby

I am building a javafx project using netbeans and am using derby database for that.
I have two tables, `BOOK` and `ISSUE`.
I want to create a `BEFORE INSERT trigger ON ISSUE` table which checks for the value of a boolean field called "available" in the BOOK table.
A button called BookIssue when pressed, should check the following trigger.
If the value of "available" is false, a warning message should pop up, else the insert operation must be executed.
I am not able to get the trigger command right.

```
String trigger = "CREATE TRIGGER toIssue NO CASCADE BEFORE INSERT ON ISSUE"
            + " FOR EACH ROW"
            + " BEGIN"
            + "     SELECT isAvail from BOOK WHERE id = '"+ bookId + "'"
            + "     IF isAvail = false"
            + "         THEN RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR(-20001,'Books Out of stock')"
            + "     END IF"
            + " END";
    databasehandler.execQuery(trigger);
```

I am getting following exception in my log:

```
Exception at execQuery:dataHandlerSyntax error: Encountered "BEGIN" at line 1, column 71.
```

Could someone help me with this! I couldn't find any other place which had a similar issue with derby.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want:  `ExecuteNonQuery()`.

In addition, this line is suspect:

```
SELECT isAvail from BOOK WHERE id = '"+ bookId + "'"
```

The trigger body should look more like this:

```
DECLARE v_avail boolean;

SELECT b.isAvail INTO v_avail 
FROM BOOK b
WHERE b.id = NEW.ID;

IF NOT v_isAvail THEN
    RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR(-20001,'Books Out of stock')"
END IF;
```